# Trigger procedure on textarea attribute value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call user defined function, once `<textarea>` attribute values changes.
Attributes like height, width and val() of `<textarea>` i.e. on content change.

Your suggestion are welcome!!!

Regards,

-Pravin

Comment: The content of the textarea wouldn't affect it's CSS...can you elaborate a bit more on what's making the changes?

Comment: On change of CSS? That is change of CSS by another script?

Comment: updated the question...trigger function on change of textarea content (i.e. val() of textarea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you likely want is the `change` and `keyup` and `paste` events, like this:

```
$("textarea").bind("change keyup paste", function() {
  //this executes when the value changes
});
```

Comment: @Sinan - It doesn't work in *all* browsers, but might as well support the ones that do...the others will fire the `change` event when the `<textarea>` is blurred.

Comment: Press tab and watch what element will be triggered on keyup event: this one or next in the form (Hint:  next one).

Answer (score 1):

Textareas support a [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) which fires when the focus leaves the element after the content has changed as well as [keyup/down/press events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

You can't reliably detect a change that is triggered by JavaScript, so call whatever functions you would call on change in whatever function makes the change.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qhysQ/1

This changes on keyup, if you wish to perform a function when the textarea loses focus, change 'keyup' to 'change.'